# Exponent Laws and the Ceiling Function

Tags: exponential-function

Suppose I have $f(x) = 5^{\lceil \frac x 3 \rceil}$, where $x \in \Bbb N$.

If I were to simplify $f(x+4)$, can I do the following: $f(x+4) = 5 ^{\lceil \frac {x+4} 3 \rceil} = 5^{\lceil {\frac x 3} \rceil} \cdot 5^{\lceil \frac 4 3 \rceil}$, by the exponent law 1.

Or is this not applicable with the ceiling function?

Comment: You are assuming that ceiling(x+y)=ceiling(x)+ceiling(y), which is not true in general. In your example, this failure can be seen when x=2

Answer (score 0):

First, I urge you to graph ceiling function on a calculator to get a good grasp. 
$$x=1$$ is one counterexample. There are infinitely many.
So, the exponent rule does not apply to the ceiling function.